# minimize question with lagrange

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

Q. Minimize 
$$
\mathrm{f} = {1 \over 2}
\left(x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3}\right) \ \mbox{subject to}\
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
{\displaystyle\mathrm{g}_{1}\left(X\right)}
& {\displaystyle =} & {\displaystyle x_{1} - x_{2} =  0}
\\[1mm]
{\displaystyle \mathrm{g}_{2}\left(X\right)} &
{\displaystyle =} & {\displaystyle x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} - 1
= 0}
\end{array}\right.
$$ 
Is this problem can solve with Lagrange multiplier ??.
It's my first time learning, so I'm not good at it.
Please someone help me !.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know about lagrange multiplier? Can you solve the resulting system?

Comment: Please, see [MSE-$\displaystyle\texttt{MathJax}$-$\displaystyle\LaTeX$-Tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Yes, this problem can be solved with Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: Due to the restriction $x_1+x_2+x_3 = 1$ we have $f = \frac 12$